# release memory used in python function composition

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I am dealing with large arrays and huge number of loops, while the script always failed because of memory limit or bus error.

Now I want to optimize the code a little bit, say release memory using `del` and `gc.collect()` as much as possible at each loop. Since I've used a bunch of nested functions, such as `result = functionA(functionB(data, time))`, I am wondering how can I release the memory in this implementation?

Basically, I want to have the same effect of doing the following:

```
B = functionB(data, time)
result = functionA(B)
del B; gc.collect()
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your latter code block isn't helping anything. When you say `functionA(functionB(data, time))` there's no reference to the result of `functionB` outside of `functionA` so it doesn't help to create one and than delete it. If after `functionA` exits the result `B` hasn't been stored anywhere else it will probably be collected instantly.

Comment: @AlexHall On CPython this is true most of the time, unless there is a reference cycle.

Comment: A nested function is one defined in the body of another function.  Passing the result of one function to another is composition, which is the basis of computation and the opposite of unusual.  As Alex said, creating and deleting a reference is useless.  Calling gc.collect() is helpful in CPython when memory is held because of cycles.  But you probably need to look elsewhere for the source of memory leaks.

Comment: @AlexHall and Terry, thanks a lot for the clarification on the composition, which should be better than reference and good for memory. Although I almost delete all the variables after they are used, but the memory still accumulates rapidly, from 4GB in 15min to 37GB at 2 hours. To look for memory leaks, maybe [this valgrind](http://blog.devork.be/2008/12/finding-memory-leaks-in-python.html) is some thing I should go for?